# Rendering Points in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I started to learn OpenGL ES 2.0 for android. As far as my understanding goes, I can render only those values whose x and y coordinates are normalized between -1 and 1. But suddenly my code behave's differently and renders values in range of -4 to 4. Is my understanding correct or Do you think something wrong with my code?

MatrixHelper class for perspective matrix:

```
public class MatrixHelper {
    public static void perspectiveM(float[] m, float yFovInDegrees, float aspect,
        float n, float f) {
        final float angleInRadians = (float) (yFovInDegrees * Math.PI / 180.0);

        final float a = (float) (1.0 / Math.tan(angleInRadians / 2.0));
        m[0] = a / aspect;
        m[1] = 0f;
        m[2] = 0f;
        m[3] = 0f;

        m[4] = 0f;
        m[5] = a;
        m[6] = 0f;
        m[7] = 0f;

        m[8] = 0f;
        m[9] = 0f;
        m[10] = -((f + n) / (f - n));
        m[11] = -1f;

        m[12] = 0f;
        m[13] = 0f;
        m[14] = -((2f * f * n) / (f - n));
        m[15] = 0f;        
    }
}
```

Here is my class to draw line:

```
public class Well {
    private static final int POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT = 2;
    private static final int COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT = 3;
    private static final int STRIDE = 
            (POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT + COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT) * BYTES_PER_FLOAT;
    private static final float[] VERTEX_DATA = {

        2.57088082911189f,2.70649737162497f, 1f, 0f, 0f,
        2.57088082911189f,2.70649737162497f, 1f, 0f, 0f,            
    };
    private final VertexArray vertexArray;

    public Well() {
        vertexArray = new VertexArray(VERTEX_DATA);
    }

    public void bindData(ColorShaderProgram colorProgram) {
        vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(0, colorProgram.getPositionAttributeLocation(), POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT, STRIDE);

        vertexArray.setVertexAttribPointer(POSITION_COMPONENT_COUNT, colorProgram.getColorAttributeLocation(), COLOR_COMPONENT_COUNT, STRIDE);
    }

    public void draw() {
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: The default viewport covers the co-ordinate range -1 to +1 for both axes. It doesn't have to though - you'll want to define a projection matrix and possibly camera transformation matrix as well to correctly map your rendered objects to the geometry of your screen: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html  Please clarify your specific problem and show your relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

check your viewMatrix

calculate right view
Take a look at this

http://pastebin.com/xnNTNc0v

Comment: This isn't an answer, this should be a comment!